# Angular dynamic value for href in div

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to implement dynamic submenu by Angular.

Currently, I set `href` by hardcode like below:

```
<ng-template #preSelectionMenuItem let-preSelections="preSelections">
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <ul class='project-tree-menu__panel-list' [attr.data-guid]="menuGuid">
            <li *ngFor="let preSelection of preSelections">
                <div class='panel-group'>
                    <div *ngIf="preSelection.subPreSelectionDtos.length>0" class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading collapsed panel-title estimate-panel-list__title' data-toggle='collapse'
                           href="#1"
                            >
                            {{ preSelection.text | translate}}
                        </div>
                        <div id="1" class='estimate-panel panel-collapse collapse'>
                            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='preSelectionMenuItem;context:{preSelections:preSelection.subPreSelectionDtos}'></ng-container>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="preSelection.subPreSelectionDtos.length==0" class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='estimate-panel-list__option project-tree-menu__item'
                           href="#1"
                            >
                            {{ preSelection.text | translate}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Actually, the value `#1` should be the `preSelection.text` which will be able to make sure referrence the correct subitems.

But If I change `#1` to `href="#{{preSelection.text}}"`, it will throw

**Can't bind to 'href' since it isn't a known property of 'div'**

Current UI
[image]

Comment: `href` is not available on a div element, it's only available for an `<a>` anchor tag. Try chaging <div>to <a>

Comment: if you wanted to have this div, you can achieve this using a click event since you can't use `href` in a div

Comment: @Manish I am trying to making `div` work, otherwise, I will need to update my css stype to for `a`

Comment: @GRD This is a multiple leve submenu, for `href`, it will show up subitems after I click the parent menu

Comment: @Edward You can apply click event in div like this `<div (click) = "onClickDiv('#1')` and when you click on div then onClickDiv mehthod will be called

Comment: @GRD How can I show submenu with onClickDiv?

Comment: @Edward a div does have a `href` attribute an `<a>` does. But a click event is available with every HTML element so you can add a event listener for click on that div and handle the menu accordingly..

Comment: @GRD - Please stop sending people to an external site with your code samples. If you want to answer something, then post as a proper answer, with all of your code here on the site. This is really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this..

```
<div
  style="margin:0.5em;"
  *ngFor="let preSelection of preSelections; let i = index">
 <div>
   <div
    (click)="onSubmenuClick(i)"
      style="background-color:'gray'; color:'white'; cursor:'pointer' ">
    <span> {{ preSelection.text }} </span>
    <span> + </span>
   </div>
   <ng-container *ngIf="clickedMenu === i">
     <div *ngFor="let subMenu of preSelection.childMenu">
       <div>{{ subMenu.menuText }}</div>
     </div>
   </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

and inside your component like this..
clickedMenu;
onSubmenuClick(index: number) {

```
  if (this.clickedMenu === index) {
    this.clickedMenu = null;
  } else {
   this.clickedMenu = index;
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you or not. Thanks!

Working demo in this link [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aiga4j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)